# How does react component pass value to the previous page component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have two component, FormComponent and OrderListComponent. There is one field on the FormComponent to ask users to select a value from a list which is from OrderListComponent. So I put a button on the field in FormComponent, when users click on that button, I use `router.push('XXXX')` to navigate the page to OrderListComponent to show all the options for user. When users click one of the options on OrderListComponent, I use `router.goBack()` to go back to FormComponent. Here is the problem, how does FormComponent get the selected value from OrderListComponent? I know that I can save the selection as a state in redux store, but I wander whether there is a more direct way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing the selected value in redux store or component state itself would be better choice for this, but you can also

- store it in **localStorage**
- store it in **sessionStorage**
- when redirecting the user back, pass it as a url parameter

If you're using any one of these methods, In `FormComponent` you can check if the value exists and perform operations accordingly.

Example code

`OrderListComponent`

```
let handleChange = (value) => {
  localStorage.orderListValue = value
}
```

This will replace any existing value as well.., Use your brain here.

`FormComponent`

```
if ( localStorage.orderListValue ) {
  console.log('Yay.. we have data');
} else {
 // ask the user to select the List first.
}
```

Comment: For the third solution, "when redirecting the user back, pass it as a url parameter", how can I pass it as a url parameter when call 'router.goBack()' method?

Comment: @ZhaoYi If you want to use the third solution, Instead of calling `router.goBack()` method, you can import `import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';` and in the function where you get the value from select field, after getting the value, do `browserHistory.push(``/url/of/the-page?value=${selectFieldValue}`` );`
**use only one backtick (`)**

Comment: This is not good for reuse component since the url is not fixed. There will be more than one components who navigate to OrderListComponent, so I do need router.goBack() function to navigate back.

Comment: You could just pass the `url` to the component as props and then the component will get the url from its props and then redirect the user to that location after getting the data., Let me check if react router allows us to pass param with goBack()

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to have state manager. Redux state will solve it elegantly. Though as [Random User mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39406948/759045); `localStorage`/`sessionStorage` can be used to do this.

But passing the values by URL will be tricky when there are too many items selected for Order.

The state can be changed so that having anything in state will give consistent output at `OrderListCompoennt`.

You can have order state and push the items to that state. And then redirect the user to `OrderListComponent` rather than doing `router.push('XXXX')`.

`OrderListComponent` will watch the state and show the items accordingly.

The `FormComponent` will also watch the order state for marking the currently added items. With this way, there will not be any `router.goBack()`; just the redirects by `router.push`

And when your app will be at `FormComponent`, order state will automatically be responsible to mark the items which are currently in order.

Comment: I know that localStorage/sessionStorage can solve this issue. But they are more useable for long term data storage. The value I want to store is only a temp value and after use it I have to clean it from storage. It is not necessary to store them on localStorage/sessionStorage. My current solution is to use redux state but redux doesn't provide a way to remove a state from the store.

Comment: For any state manager, take Redux or Flux or Reflux, there will not be any method for clearing store. Store is a big data object with necessary methods. As far as removal of items from order list is considered, pass the indexes and use slice of arrays. You would have to create your own method to remove items. To clear all items, you can set the order store to empty array. The slice method amends the array itself, so you would not need to save the new array again. I think I should add a crude example also.